# Content below first Vue component is failing to render

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm developing an incremental game, and I have three Vue components. I want two of the components to display like sibling elements would.

I'm working with Vue 2.6.10, and I tried to render two sibling components next to each other, but for some reason vue does not parse the components.

This is my HTML.

```html
   <div id="app">
        <nav-buttons :buttons="buttonMenu" />
        <tab-content>
            <linked-frame id="civilization">
                <nav-buttons :buttons="civilizationButtons" />
            </linked-frame>
            <linked-frame id="projects">
                <nav-buttons :buttons="projectButtons" />
            </linked-frame>
        </tab-content>
    </div>
```

And this is my JS (With Vue):

```js
Vue.component("nav-buttons", {
    name: "nav-buttons",
    props: ["buttons"],
    template: `
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li v-for="button in buttons" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" :href="'#'+button.name.toLowerCase()">{{button.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
});

Vue.component("linked-frame", {
    name: "linked-frame",
    props: ["id"],
    template: `
        <div :id="id" class="container tab-pane">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `
});

Vue.component("tab-content", {
    name: "tab-content",
    template: `
        <div class="tab-content">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        buttonMenu: [{ name: "Civilization" }, { name: "Projects" }],
        projectButtons: [{ name: "Military" }, { name: "Science" }, { name: "Government" }, { name: "Socioeconomic" }],
        civilizationButtons: [{ name: "Population" }, { name: "Employment" }, { name: "Pending Projects" }]
    }
});
```

I expect to see a second navbar appear when either of the top-level buttons is clicked, but the entire second component doesn't even render in the final html:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li class="nav-item">
<a data-toggle="pill" href="#civilization" class="nav-link active">Civilization</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
<a data-toggle="pill" href="#projects" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
</ul>
<!--No div for the content!-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you are using a self closing tag in a DOM template. You only want to use self closing tags in `.vue`, `jsx` and `string templates` so tha the vue compiler can handle them.

Read more about it in the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Self-closing-components-strongly-recommended) for their style guide.

You have two options.

In your index.html, replace `<nav-buttons :buttons="buttonMenu" />` with `<nav-buttons :buttons="buttonMenu"></nav-buttons>`

**Code Snippet**

```js
Vue.component("nav-buttons", {
  props: ["buttons"],
  template: `
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li v-for="button in buttons" :key="button.name" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">{{button.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
});

Vue.component("linked-frame", {
  props: ["id"],
  template: `
        <div :id="id" class="container tab-pane">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `
});

Vue.component("tab-content", {
  template: `
        <div class="tab-content">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    buttonMenu: [{
      name: "Civilization"
    }, {
      name: "Projects"
    }],
    projectButtons: [{
      name: "Military"
    }, {
      name: "Science"
    }, {
      name: "Government"
    }, {
      name: "Socioeconomic"
    }],
    civilizationButtons: [{
      name: "Population"
    }, {
      name: "Employment"
    }, {
      name: "Pending Projects"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <nav-buttons :buttons="buttonMenu"></nav-buttons>
  <tab-content>
    <linked-frame id="civilization">
      <nav-buttons :buttons="civilizationButtons" />
    </linked-frame>
    <linked-frame id="projects">
      <nav-buttons :buttons="projectButtons" />
    </linked-frame>
  </tab-content>
</div>
```

Or move the app template to the Vue definition.

**Snippet**

```js
Vue.component("nav-buttons", {
  props: ["buttons"],
  template: `
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li v-for="button in buttons" :key="button.name" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">{{button.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    `
});

Vue.component("linked-frame", {
  props: ["id"],
  template: `
        <div :id="id" class="container tab-pane">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `
});

Vue.component("tab-content", {
  template: `
        <div class="tab-content">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    `
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `
<div>
  <nav-buttons :buttons="buttonMenu" />
  <tab-content>
    <linked-frame id="civilization">
      <nav-buttons :buttons="civilizationButtons" />
    </linked-frame>
    <linked-frame id="projects">
      <nav-buttons :buttons="projectButtons" />
    </linked-frame>
  </tab-content>
 </div>
  `,
  data: {
    buttonMenu: [{
      name: "Civilization"
    }, {
      name: "Projects"
    }],
    projectButtons: [{
      name: "Military"
    }, {
      name: "Science"
    }, {
      name: "Government"
    }, {
      name: "Socioeconomic"
    }],
    civilizationButtons: [{
      name: "Population"
    }, {
      name: "Employment"
    }, {
      name: "Pending Projects"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Great! I updated the answer with two options for fixing this.